# Background Color Issues

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

Can someone please assist me on why my background color of the frame is not being set.   Is it possible to set the background color within the `Paint()` or must it be done in the `JColor` constructor

I am supposed to do the following for the BG color-

Write A GUI application that displays a single `JButton` and any background color you choose.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Curtis
 */
public class JColor extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
Font myFont = new Font("Playbill", Font.PLAIN, 28);
JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
Color bgColor = new Color(255, 97, 3);
Color txtColor = new Color(0, 0, 205);
String firstName = "Curtis";
String lastName = "Sizemore";

public JColor()
        {
            super("String Painting Fun");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout (new BorderLayout());
            add(myButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

@Override
public void paint(Graphics e)
{
    super.paint(e);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final int TALL = 200;
    final int WIDE = 250;
    JColor frame = new JColor();
    frame.setSize(WIDE, TALL);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
}
```

Comment: _Is it possible to set the background color within the Paint()_ **NO** - the general rule is never-ever change component state in the paint cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling it on the `ContentPane` instance (more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html))

```
public JColor() {
    super("String Painting Fun");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(myButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);//<- update
}
```

Comment: @Curt Sizemore, Is it possible to set the background color within the `Paint()`? to answer this, yes, do the same as above (`getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);`) just add it to the `Paint()` after the `super.paint(e);`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Are you suggesting to call `getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);` within the  `paint` method? This would be a terrible idea. It should be called in the constructor/init-method or in some setter-method/update-method.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet, I was simply answering the Op's question, but yes I do agree, this would not be very good.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Ok, but from your comment is does not look this clear. I would clearly advise against doing such thing in the paint method. If the OP needs to choose the background at painting time, then he can just paint the background "himself" with the Graphics parameter (g.setColor(), g.fillRect).

Comment: @DavidKroukamp just to emphasize Guillaume's comments: your comment it simply wrong or a correct but useless technicality as _yes it is possible to code mistakes, even if they are severe_ :-)

Comment: @kleopatra yes I have got a way better understanding of what is good.ad in swing, sorry for my previous wrong comments (+1)... You are the smartest lady programmer I know, but your age 92?  I hope you live until 200yo or else you **were** the smartest I knew :P